# "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" error in R for continuous variable

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have exported data (2 columns) from SQL. When I try to use ggplots (qplot) to create a histogram, I am getting the error: "Discrete value supplied to continuous scale." However, the two columns I am trying to make histograms for are continuous variables. Data looks like this:

V1: 321.12, 346.54, 4563.45, etc.

V2: 2, 1, 4, 6, 20, 24, 12, etc.

My R code looks like this:

```
qplot(myTable$V1,
geom="histogram", 
main = "Histogram for V1", 
xlab = "V1", 
ylab = "Count", 
fill = I("green"), 
col = I("blue"), 
alpha = (.8)) + scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) 
        + scale_x_continuous(labels = comma) + theme(legend.position = "none")
```

In SQL, both variables are floating type variables. How do I make R treat these variables as continuous, not discrete?

Note: Other posts suggest using - (a) as.numeric() in R, but then I get the error message "“Warning message: NAs introduced by coercion” or (b) geom_box in R; but I would like to use geom_hist.

Comment: Check the structure of your data with `str(myTable)` to make sure they are numerics once you read them in. Depending on which SQL connector you use, this could get messed up.

Comment: please provide a sample of your data